# Qt Quick - What is the correct way to create a GridView with variable row height?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, qt5

I'm Developing an application with Qt 5.13.0 on a Windows 10 professional computer. I need to create a Whatsapp like message view, and to achieve that, I used a GridView component as a base. However, in order to draw the messages correctly, I need to create each GridView row with a different height, depending on the message text.

But to my surprise, I could not find any solution on the internet to achieve that, although I thought it was a simple formality. I tried a solution by myself, which I attached below, however it doesn't work. The issue is that all the rows take the height of the last resized one.

I have no doubt that Qt can do this, unfortunately, I have been looking for days now, and I can not find a solution to this issue. I simply have no idea about how to achieve that. So someone can explain to me how to create a GridView with variable height rows, or if the GridWiew isn't the appropriate component to do that, whcih I should use instead?

Here is my qss file:

```css
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Grid view")
    color: "#ffffff"

    ColumnLayout
    {
        transformOrigin: Item.Center
        spacing: 0
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        /**
        * Grid view item
        */
        Component
        {
            id: itGridItem

            Item
            {
                Column
                {
                    Rectangle
                    {
                        property int messageWidth: (gvMessageGrid.cellWidth / 2) - 50

                        id: itemRect
                        x: senderIsMyself ? 25 : gvMessageGrid.cellWidth - (25 + messageWidth)
                        y: 5
                        width: messageWidth
                        height: itemTextID.height + 20
                        color: senderIsMyself ? "#d5d5d5" : "#800b940e"
                        radius: 5
                        clip: true

                        Text
                        {
                            id: itemTextID
                            width: parent.width - 20
                            text: itemText
                            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                            textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
                            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                            font.family: "Segoe UI Emoji"
                            font.pixelSize: 18
                            anchors.margins: 10
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            color: "#101010"
                        }

                        onHeightChanged: gvMessageGrid.cellHeight = height + 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
        * Messages grid view
        */
        GridView
        {
            id: gvMessageGrid
            y: 0
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            clip: true
            contentWidth: 700
            contentHeight: 300
            cellWidth: contentWidth
            cellHeight: 150
            model: lmGridModel
            delegate: itGridItem

            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar
            {
                visible: true
            }

            onWidthChanged: cellWidth = width
        }
    }
}
```

**--- Edited on October 18, 2019**

Following the eyllanesc suggestion below, here are 2 screenshots of what I want and what I get:

**what I want**

---

[image]

**what I get**

---

[image]

**NOTE** I'm using several languages, for test purposes, because my application must have international support. However the issue I face has nothing to do with that, i.e it's not an error with text calculation, because 1. The green rect sizes around the text are always correct, and 2. I face the exact same issue with pure English text.

Comment: Why is a GridView necessary? , you could show images of what you get and another of what you want to get

Comment: I did it, see above

Comment: There is no grid here. Use a `ListView`. Also what's the deal with the `Item { Column { Rectangle { /* ... */} } }` for the delegate, why not just `Rectangle { /* ... */}`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use ListView instead of GridView. You can easily view anything inside full-width list item. Let me share with you my `ListDelegate` class from an old project. Pay attention to usage of `isIncoming` property in anchor binding, for example:

```
anchors {
    left: isIncoming? undefined : parent.left
    right: isIncoming? parent.right : undefined
}
```

Full listing:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

import "units.js" as Units

Rectangle {
    id: chatMsgDelegRoot

    property bool isIncoming: !model.out
    property bool isSelected: model.isSelected

    signal clicked(int index)

    width: parent.width
    height: dlgColumn.height + Units.gu(2.5)
    color: "#edf1f5"

    Column {
        id: dlgColumn
        spacing: Units.gu(4)
        width: parent.width
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        BorderImage {
            id: borderImage

            source: isIncoming?
                        (isSelected ? "/images/img/MsgOut_Selected_2.png" : "/images/img/MsgOut_2.png") :
                        (isSelected ? "/images/img/MsgIn_Selected_2.png" : "/images/img/MsgIn_2.png")

            // Texture-dependent.
            border {
                left: isIncoming? 20 : 30
                top: 20
                right: isIncoming? 30 : 20
                bottom: 35
            }

            anchors {
                left: isIncoming? undefined : parent.left
                right: isIncoming? parent.right : undefined
            }
            width: Math.max(content.width + Units.gu(15), Units.gu(21))
            height: content.height + Units.gu(9)

            MouseArea {
                id: msgDelegateMa
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: chatMsgDelegRoot.clicked(model.index)
            }

            Loader {
                id: content
                sourceComponent: model.type === "Text" ? textComponent : controlComponent
                anchors {
                    left: isIncoming? undefined : parent.left
                    right: isIncoming? parent.right : undefined
                    leftMargin: Units.gu(10)
                    rightMargin: Units.gu(10)
                    top: parent.top
                    topMargin: Units.gu(4)
                }
            }

            Text {
                text: model.date.toTimeString()
                font.pointSize: 8
                font.italic: true;
                color: "lightgrey"
                anchors {
                    left: isIncoming? undefined : parent.left
                    right: isIncoming? parent.right : undefined
                    rightMargin: Units.gu(7.5)
                    leftMargin: Units.gu(7.5)
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                    bottomMargin: Units.gu(1)
                }
            }
        } // BorderImage
    } // Column

    // TODO To separate files.
    Component {
        id: textComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: textComponentRoot

            color: "#00000000"
            width: msgText.paintedWidth
            height: msgText.height

            Text {
                id: msgText
                font.pointSize: 10
                textFormat: Text.RichText
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                width: chatMsgDelegRoot.width * 0.7
                text: model.body
                color: isSelected? "white" : "black"
            }
        }
    } // Component

    Component {
        id: controlComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: textComponentRoot

            color: "#00000000"
            width: innerColumn.width
            height: innerColumn.height

            Column {
                id: innerColumn
                spacing: Units.gu(1)

                Text {
                    id: fileNameText
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                    width: chatMsgDelegRoot.width * 0.7
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    text: "File transfer: " + model.body
                    color: isSelected? "white" : "black"
                }

                Row {
                    id: innerRow
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    spacing: Units.gu(1)

                    SimpleButton {
                        id: allowBtn
                        width: Units.gu(15)
                        height: Units.gu(8)
                        text: "Allow"
                    }

                    SimpleButton {
                        id: denyBtn
                        width: Units.gu(15)
                        height: Units.gu(8)
                        text: "Deny"
                    }
                }
            } // Column
        }
    } // Component
}
```